# Bash script last_sudo to display the last sudo entry in auth.log

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a bash script in /usr/local/bin, which does the following.

If the current user is a regular user, the script displays the last sudo entry in auth.log for that user. If the current user is the root, it requires one argument, which is the username for whom to display the last sudo entry in auth.log.  Perform the necessary check on script usage. Running this script as a regular user (even as “test” or a future user) should not require preceding it with sudo.

Sample execution:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/last_sudo (or, # /usr/local/bin/last_sudo john) 
Dec 20 16:05:16 john-linux sudo:    john : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/john/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/reboot now
```

```
#!/bin/bash

i=$(whoami)
log=/var/log/auth.log
if [$i=!root]
egrep $i $log
```

Comment: I have removed 15% ... copied by mistake...

Yes i know .. last but i want to grep from /var/log/auth.log only

Comment: Why not `if [ "$EUID" -ne '0' ]; then grep "$USER" "/var/log/auth.log"; fi | tail -n 1` (presuming your `auth.log` is a plain text file and not in `wtmp` format -- otherwise you will need `last` as suggested)

Comment: Yes.. thanks david amd chooroba.........If the current user is the root, it requires one argument how do i do this? or, # /usr/local/bin/last_sudo john

Comment: You would either create a second helper script, or just write a `function`. The test the `$UID` (or `$EUID`, which should be the same here) and then if `root` call `function` else call `function sudo` (passing `sudo` as the first argument). (your `function` could simply be a call to `/usr/local/bin/last_sudo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improvising on what you have written:

```
#!/bin/bash

me=$(whoami)
log=/var/log/auth.log
if [[ "$me" = "root" ]]; then
  [[ -z "$1" ]] && printf "Usage: $0 username\n" >&2 && exit 2
  user="$1"
fi

grep '/bin/sudo/' "$log" | grep "$user" | tail -1
exit 0
```

Comment: This script probably isn't going to work on most Linux boxes because /var/log/auth.log is usually only readable by root. So the last bit of your script will give you a permission denied or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

No such script exists, you will have to write one.

Here's a (untested) skeleton:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -v SUDO_UID ]]; then
  grep '/bin/sudo' /var/log/auth.log | grep "$SUDO_USER" | tail -1
else
  if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "You're running this script as root, please provide a username" >&2
    echo "usage: $0 USERNAME"
  else
    grep '/bin/sudo' /var/log/auth.log | grep "$1" | tail -1
  fi
fi
```

This script will need to be run via sudo, because `/var/log/auth.log` and cousins are not world readable by default.

Comment: I have chmod 0777 /var/log/auth.log just for learning....  the output is not correct... tried to execute with "arapi" and root as well didn't worked.

Comment: What is not correct? What is the output you expected, and what is the output you get?

Comment: "/usr/local/bin/last_sudo john"
 
Dec 20 16:05:16 john-linux sudo:    john : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/john/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/reboot now

Comment: output im expecting the above one.. when i type "last_sudo test" as root i should get output as above commented.

Comment: sorry.. your script is also somewhat working.. i change to grep 'sudo' /var/log/auth.log

Comment: even the test user also needed to pass argument... SCREENSHOT http://imgur.com/a/GKyQO 

im also having issue with grep or tailing.. it is printing the last "sudo" regardless user details

Comment: @PraVeeNNelsonPaul  the script assumes that it is run via sudo, in which case `$SUDO_UID` will be set. If you run it normally, it shouldn't have access to read `/var/log/auth.log` at all, unless you've changed the permissions on that file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
me=$(whoami)
log=/var/log/auth.log
if [[ "$me" = "root" ]]; then
[[ -z "$1" ]] && printf "Usage: $0 username\n" >&2 && exit 2
user="$1"
fi
grep -e 'sudo.*COMMAND' $log | tail -n 1
exit 0
```

thank you everyone ... this script is wanted i think...

codeforester.. i modified a bit .. it is what i wanted.. thank you